# How to convert pdf from buffer using node-imagemagick

Tags: node.js, pdf, imagemagick

I want to convert pdf file using imagemagick from a buffer that I get from URL contain pdf (not pdf file, so I don't have to save the pdf first and run imagemagick). I use node-imagemagick and in docs is just showing the convert() method with a file path like below: (kittens.jpg)

```js
im.convert(['kittens.jpg', '-resize', '25x120', 'kittens-small.jpg'], 
function(err, stdout){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
});
```

But If I want to use buffer, how can I do this? Here is my code

```
request.get({ url: 'url to pdf', encoding: null }, (err, resp, body) => {
  im.convert([body, '-resize', '25x120', 'kittens-small.jpg'], 
  function(err, stdout){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check the source code of node-imagemagik: [Link to code](https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick/blob/master/imagemagick.js).

node-imagemagik is a wrapper for the `convert` tool.

The convert function is defined as follows

```
exports.convert = function(args, timeout, callback) {
  var procopt = {encoding: 'binary'};
  if (typeof timeout === 'function') {
    callback = timeout;
    timeout = 0;
  } else if (typeof timeout !== 'number') {
    timeout = 0;
  }
  if (timeout && (timeout = parseInt(timeout)) > 0 && !isNaN(timeout))
    procopt.timeout = timeout;
  return exec2(exports.convert.path, args, procopt, callback);
}
exports.convert.path = 'convert';
```

It assumes you give the same arguments as in the commandline, i.e. a source image path. However, `convert` supports input from stdin, and this is how you can feed your pdf data to the process.

In the source code, there is an usefull example. The definition of a resize function, wich accepts binary data and feeds it into the convert function with the appropiate parameters.

```
var resizeCall = function(t, callback) {
  var proc = exports.convert(t.args, t.opt.timeout, callback);
  if (t.opt.srcPath.match(/-$/)) {
    if ('string' === typeof t.opt.srcData) {
      proc.stdin.setEncoding('binary');
      proc.stdin.write(t.opt.srcData, 'binary');
      proc.stdin.end();
    } else {
      proc.stdin.end(t.opt.srcData);
    }
  }
  return proc;
}

exports.resize = function(options, callback) {
  var t = exports.resizeArgs(options);
  return resizeCall(t, callback)
}
```

The call to `convert` is made replacing the input filename with "-". The equivalen usage from the terminal would be something like:

```
my_process_that_outputs_pdf | convert - <convertion options here...> my_output.png
```